# debugging a VS2010 application in production

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'll try to clarify the situation before I ask the question.
We have written an application (c#) that automatically imports emails and converts them to PDF and then uploads them a Document Management System of document processing system. We have installed this application at more then 100 customers systems. But there is one customer that has random problems with importing there emails. We have narrowed it down to there own emails from within the company that are going wrong.

What i want is to debug the application within there production environment. They don't have a test or acceptance environment. I would like to do this with the least impact for the prod. system. Preverbal from a remote desktop computer or something like that.

How can I debug the application without installing VS on the system that has the faulty application running?

I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Server usually come with stripped down version of Visual Studio. That might help. It will be just an editor though.

Comment: Can you install the remote debugging tools and then connect to it remotely?  If your code logs exceptions, you could also copy the appropriate .pdb files to the machine so that your stack traces will show line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

search for 'remote debugging', something like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y7f5zaaa.aspx

... but remote debugging c# apps is a pain.

Comment: Our code logs exceptions also to the system application log. I will look into your suggestions and get back with the results.

Comment: I'll also look into the remote debugging info. I can set it up on our test environment and see how it works. Thanks for the head up :-) I already figured out that it was going to be a pain in the .....